# test_data emptied after one run of SGD

Tags: python, neural-network

This is about the programming of the zipcode recognition in the very popular book "Neural Networks and Deep Learning" by Michael Nielsen
[link](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html). Michal Daniel Dobrzanski provides a Python3 version [link](https://github.com/MichalDanielDobrzanski/DeepLearningPython)

I noticed that the `test_data` (initially 10000 data) is emptied after each learning using `SGD` from `network.py`. To have a second learning, I need to reload the data using `mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()` from `mnist_loader.py`. I copied the code for `SGD`:

```
   def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, test_data=None):
        training_data = list(training_data)
        n = len(training_data)

        if test_data:
            test_data = list(test_data)
            n_test = len(test_data)

        for j in range(epochs):
            random.shuffle(training_data)
            mini_batches = [
                training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]
                for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size)]
            for mini_batch in mini_batches:
                self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
            if test_data:
                print("Epoch {} : {} / {}".format(j,self.evaluate(test_data),n_test))
            else:
                print("Epoch {} complete".format(j))
```

Initially, `len(test_data)` returns `10000`. Then I run the code

```
net = Network([784, 100, 10])
net.SGD(training_data, 30, 10, 0.001, test_data=test_data)
```

`test_data` is certainly not empty during these 30 iterates. However, `len(test_data)` returns `0` after the execution of the code.
This seems strange to me, since the only change to `test_data` in the method `SGD` is
 `test_data = list(test_data)`

Am I the only one having this issue? I use Visual Studio Code and run the codes in an interactive window.